# Calling a method from another class in Java?

Tags: java

I have two classes below and I want to call the SetPlace method in my main program.

```
public class Place
{
//variables
//constructors
//methods

    private String place; //only accessible within the class

    public Place()
    {
        place = null; // strings initialised as null as it doesn;t refer to anything yet -1 for int
    }

    public void SetPlace()
    {
        Place p1 = new Place();
        p1.place="Dungeon";
    }

}

public class Main {
    public static void main (String []args)
    {
          Place p1 = new Place();          
    }
}
```

How do I pass the SetPlace method to the Main Method and print out "Dungeon".

Any assistance is welcomed!

Comment: You don't have to do `place = null;` in the constructor. By default, reference place will point to  null.

Comment: `p1.setPlace("Dungeon")` should work? Change the `setPlace()` method to take `String` as argument.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to create an instance of that class like: `Place place = new Place()` and then `place.SetPlace()`.

Or you can make that function `static` so the it can be called within main without having to create a new instance of it. Note that setters probably shouldn't be static, but if you want to access a function from another class, this is how to do it.

Comment: Setters should usually be *non-static*. :)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar Quite true but I just wanted to add that so he or she can know it is an option, I'll edit that into the post.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to write the calling statement in your main method like this:

```
public static void main (String []args)
{
    Place p1 = new Place();
    p1.SetPlace();// added here
}
```

But you may have made two mistakes: writing the `SetPlace` in a wrong way, and lacking of "print" statement.
a setter usually looks like this:

```
SetPlace(String place){
    this.place = place; // instead of creating a new instance of Place
}
```

and you can use *System.out* if you want to print something onto console:

```
// write this method in class Place
String getPlace(){
    return place;
}
...
// call it in Main
System.out.println(p1.getPlace());
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work like that. You can't pass the method as a parameter but refence to your objects/instances. In your case since you already created an instance you can just call

```
p1.SetPlace();
```

Also if you want to print it to console you should write a toString() method in your Place class then call it with a System.out call like following

```
public String toString()
{
  return place;
}
```

in main method

```
System.out.println(p1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of The String place in order to print it, you'll also need to create a getPlace() method that returns place.

And in the main method you do

```
p1.SetPlace();
System.out.println(p1.getPlace());
```

Answer (score 0):

Create setter method for place.

Note :- as per Java guidelines ...method name must start with small character and must follow camel case.

```
public void setPlace(String place)
{

    this.place=place;
}
```

Create getter method for place and to get value call this method using reference variable of Place class.

```
public String getPlace()
{
  return place;
}
```

Now from Main class call setter method.

```
 Place p1 = new Place();  
 p1.setPlace("New York");
```